# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gradle

> ~/myApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml:102:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.

And for `colorPrimary`, and `colorPrimaryDark`.
This is a bare-bones project,  targeting version 21+.

For posterity, see my `values/`:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
                <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
                <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
                <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

**values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="accent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dcousens.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    .. snip
}
```

There are many questions under this name,  but the resolutions for them are bumping `compileSdkVersion` to at least 21.
This has already been done,  and the error persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `android:Theme.Material`, rather than the suggested `Theme.AppCompat`, you must use the `android:` prefix on each item.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Using `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat` is recommended for all API levels as things have continued to change since API 21 and AppCompat continues to add fixes up through even API 24.